# Manage one remote server using my mac as master with Puppet

Tags: puppet

I have just started studying Puppet. I understand that puppet can work in solo mode and in the master/agents configuration.

### Ideal Use Case

I have a server on Digital Ocean, I would like to use the Puppet GUI to manage the remote server from my MAC, (if possible without running a VM). Is this possible or I am obliged to rent another server that run as a master (if I want to use the Puppet GUI)?

Comment: Not sure how well that would work out. The Puppet master/node relationship is in reality a server/client relationship. Your workstation is not a server.

Comment: The workstation *can* be a server, but the OP has not made clear what GUI should actually run. Building a Linux VM would likely help his cause, because MacOS would be an odd choice to run the master side of things.